# Using cvWarpAffine to crop image in openCV

Tags: c++, opencv, affinetransform, resize-crop

If I want to crop image **center** at `(x,y)` with **window size** `ws` using
`void cvWarpAffine(const CvArr* src, CvArr* dst, const CvMat* map_matrix,
int flags=CV_INTER_LINEAR+CV_WARP_FILL_OUTLIERS, CvScalar fillval=cvScalarAll(0) )`
in openCV, how should I set the parameters of **transformation matrix**? I am confused about how to set the default parameters of other transformations except crop?

**P.S.** In my situation I also want to crop the point centre at edge and need padding in the fix window. So use `cv:rect` will be more complecated to deal with the edge.

Comment: for cropping it is easier to use submatrices/subimages. And all in all it is better to use the C++ API if possible (you are using the C-API atm). Is there a reason why you want to use warping instead of subimaging?

Comment: I just use this function to crop image sometime. I will also use `cvWarpAffine` to do **Data Set Augmentation** (Augmenting the data set by repeatedly transforming the training examples is a commonly
employed technique to reduce the network's generalization error) in convolutional neural networks. So I think as `cvWarpAffine`  can also crop images, it's better to use it.

Comment: Why do you specifically want to do it with warpAffine ?

Comment: To add to Micka's and beaker's points you could also try **translation**, **rotation** and **shear** to augment your data

Comment: I mean that sometimes I don't have to augment my data, so I want to use the same function to crop images.

Comment: And I'm pretty sure this function can crop images. @beaker Here is how the matrix defined in lua

Comment: Here is how the matrix defined in lua. `local m = {1, 0, -dim4, 0, 1, -dim3}
m = mul32({1, 0, params.trans[1], 0, 1, params.trans[2]}, m) -- translate
m = mul32({params.scale[1], 0, 0, 0, params.scale[2], 0}, m) -- scale
local c = math.cos(params.phi)
local s = math.sin(params.phi)
m = mul32({c, s, 0, -s, c, 0}, m) -- rotate
m = mul32({1, params.hshear, 0, 0, 1, 0}, m) -- shear
m = mul32({1, 0, (ws - 1) / 2, 0, 1, (ws - 1) / 2}, m)`

Comment: in the C++ syntax of warpaffine you can choose the destination image size afaik.

Comment: @Micka Yes, you're correct, I was wrong. The output image is the size of the `dsize` argument, not the same size as the input image. I would still be worried about interpolation changing the image, but I guess it could work.

Comment: @beaker as said in the beginning, I wouldn't use warping for cropping. Just use subimaging: `cv::Mat croppedMat = orignalMat(cv::Rect(startX, startY, newWidth, newHeight));` and maybe add a `.clone()` if you need a deep copy instead of sharing the memory.

Comment: @Micka I agree totally.

Comment: But this way will be more complecated to deal with the edge. In my situation I also want to crop the point centre at edge and need padding in the fix window